# A conjecture related to Viviani's theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In the following picture, related to Viviani's theorem, $A=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\alpha\beta$ and $A'=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\gamma^2$. We suppose $\beta>\alpha$ and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma>0$.

[image: The areas $A$ and $A'$ in a Viviani's theorem framework.]

> Is there any way to infer that $\gamma^2=2\alpha\beta$ or, $\gamma^2<2\alpha\beta$, or $\gamma^2>2\alpha\beta$?

Comment: I believe it depends. These can take on many values. Is there any relation between $A$ and $A'$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Jeffery. I have no idea if there is a relation between $A$ and $A'$. Since I am not an expert, and I had troubles even to find the expressions of these areas, I thought that maybe somebody more into Viviani's theorem could already know a method to evaluate this relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you refer to three segments $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ originating from a point $P$ inside an equilateral triangle and perpendicular to its three sides. Polygon $A$ is a parallelogram having $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as sides and $B$ is an equilateral triangle with side $\gamma$.

If you intend those properties to hold for any $P$ inside the triangle, then they are certainly false. To check, take for instance $P$ on the left side: then $\alpha=0$ and $\gamma>0$, whereas $\alpha>0$ and $\gamma=0$ if $P$ is on the right side.

EDIT.

Asking for $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ to be positive doesn't change the situation: you can place $P$ so that $\gamma$ is almost vanishing while $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not (diagram below, left), or vice versa (diagram below, right).

[image]

EDIT 2.

If you are asking, instead, for the locus of points such that $\gamma^2≷2\alpha\beta$, then it is not difficult to find that $\gamma^2=2\alpha\beta$ along an arc of ellipse, passing through two vertices of the triangle and tangent there to two sides.

To prove that, it is convenient to use an [oblique system of coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ObliqueCoordinates.html) with $x$ axis along side $AB$ of the triangle and $y$ axis along side $AC$ (see diagram below). 
For simplicity I also set $AB=AC=1$.
Coordinates $(x,y)$ of point $P$ have a simple relation with $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$
\alpha={\sqrt3\over2}y,\quad \beta={\sqrt3\over2}x
\quad\text{and}\quad
\gamma={\sqrt3\over2}-\alpha-\beta\quad
\text{by Viviani's theorem.}
$$
Plugging these into $\gamma^2=2\alpha\beta$ gives a simple equation for $P$:
$$
(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=1.
$$
In orthogonal coordinates that would be the equation of a circle with center $O=(1,1)$ and unit radius. In oblique coordinates that is instead the equation of an ellipse, whose properties can be deduced from the equation:

- the ellipse is tangent to coordinate axes at $B$ and $C$ and has center $O$;
- the coordinates of its vertices $R$, $S$, $U$, $V$ can be found from the intersection of the ellipse with lines $AO$ and $UV$ having equations $y=x$ and $x+y=2$; it turns out that those vertices have coordinates ${1\pm 1/\sqrt2}$;
- from that it follows that $RO=\sqrt{3/2}$ and $UO=1/\sqrt2$.

Once you know the length of the axes of the ellipse and their direction, the ellipse is completely defined.

[image]

Comment: Sure. Thanks, Aretino. Maybe I should have mentioned that it must be $\alpha,\beta,\gamma>0$ and, moreover, that at least $\alpha>\beta$, in the sense that we suppose that at least two segments are not equal to each other. I add it in the Question.

Comment: Those additions don't change the conclusion: you can place $P$ so that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both very small while $\gamma$ is not, or the other way around.

Comment: Dear Aretino, thank you very much. Very clever explanations! I see very well your points. Very beautiful the connection with the ellipse! How can one prove this fact?

Comment: Great proof! To me it would have been really hard to get it. Thanks for your detailed and illuminating explanations!