# A question about a right triangle contained in an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In this picture,

[image: Rectangle triangle inside a equilateral one]

$ABC$ is an equilateral triangle, whereas $ABP$ is a rectangle triangle. Let $P$ be inside the equilateral triangle, and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ three segments such that they sum up to the side of $ABC$ (and also to the hypotenuse of $ABP$, by construction).

> Is it true that $P$ belongs to the red circle if and only $\gamma^2=2\alpha\beta$?

Comment: Consider *ABP* and apply Pythagoras' Theorem (and its converse). What can you get?

Comment: Hmmm Thanks Tony, but I don't get it :(

Comment: You mean $(\alpha+\gamma)^2+(\beta+\gamma)^2=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2$...

Comment: Please use *"right triangle"*, *"right-angled triangle"*, or *"rectangled triangle"* (see e.g. [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle)). *"rectangle triangle"* is quite confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I correct it.

Comment: Use Pythagors thm. $ (\alpha+\gamma)^2+(\beta+\gamma)^2=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2 $  Expand it.Cancell equal terms on each side of the equation and ...if that tallies then $P$ lies on the semi-circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AB$ is the diameter of the red circle. If $P$ belongs to the red circle, $\angle APB=90^\circ$ (semi-circle). So by the Pythagorean theorem, $AB^2=AP^2+PB^2\implies (\alpha+\gamma+\beta)^2=(\alpha+\gamma)^2+(\beta+\gamma)^2\implies\gamma^2=2\alpha\beta.$

The converse of the Pythagorean theorem takes care of the "$\Leftarrow$" direction.

Comment: Yes, I see! Thanks a lot, Poyea (and also thanks to Tony, I got the same solution thanks to his  suggestion).